# How I can arrange these data in R

Tags: r

```html
data <- data.frame(
Flower = 1:15,
EA1 = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1),
EA2 = c(4, 5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 6, 4, 5, 4, 4, 6, 4),
EA3 = c(8, 9, 7, 8, 9, 9, 8, 7, 8, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9, 7),
EA4 = c(12, 12, 11, 11, 10, 10, 11, 12, 10, 11, 11, 10, 12, 12, 10),
Score1 = c(9, 10, 15, 11, 11, 16, 12, 6, 8, 9, 14, 12, 12, 11, 9),
Score2 = c(15, 12, 9, 13, 10, 12, 12, 6, 8, 9, 9, 14, 12, 8, 13),
Score3 = c(12, 9, 13, 13, 12, 14, 12, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 8, 14, 13),
Score4 = c(9, 9, 11, 14, 11, 14, 11, 7, 11, 8, 14, 8, 12, 11, 12)
)
```

I want to get the following heading columns: Flower, EAR, Time ( which is based on Score, i.e., 1,2,3 ,4... and Score So the student raw should have, in this example, 15 raw for each Flower (111111111111111, an 2222...), and the other columns then completed.

Comment: `reshape(data, -1, dir='long', sep='', idvar = 1)`

Comment: Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , v.names, value = list(`1` = c(1L,  : 
  column name "" cannot match any column

Comment: It seems you have different col names. You will have to include the colnames that you have or adjust the pattern we gave to match the colnames that you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we could use this to get the output below, which reshapes your 60 EA values and your 60 Scores into 60 rows, distinguished by 15 Flowers and 4 Time values each. The `names_pattern` is a regular expression to capture the alphabetic characters first, and send those to a column with that name, and capture any number of digits at the end, to send to the Time column.

```
data |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-Flower, names_pattern = "([[:alpha:]])(\\d+)",
                      names_to = c(".value", "Time"))
```

Or `tidyr::pivot_longer(-1,...` if it's the first column that should be untouched, and you don't want to specify by name.

to get

```
# A tibble: 60 × 4
   Flower Time     EA Score
    <int> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1      1 1         1     9
 2      1 2         4    15
 3      1 3         8    12
 4      1 4        12     9
 5      2 1         1    10
 6      2 2         5    12
 7      2 3         9     9
 8      2 4        12     9
 9      3 1         2    15
10      3 2         6     9
# ℹ 50 more rows
```

Comment: This is good, but when I change the column names, I get the wrong Score. Can we do better?

Comment: @user330 why do you want to change colunm names? What are you changing them to?

Comment: @user330 the code provided here solves the issue